# Cursor : hand not working on chrome and mozilla but works on ie

Tags: css

Css cursor:hand; this is working in Internet Explorer, but not in other browsers...why is this?

```
<input type="button" class="submit" value="submit" />
.submit {
background: transparent;
border-top: 2px solid #00F;
border-right: 0;
border-bottom: 2px solid #00F;
border-left: 0;
color: #00F;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
cursor:hand;
 }
```

Answer (score 32):

It not working because the consortium is renamed it to `pointer`. So change `hand` to `pointer` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `cursor: pointer`

Read: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 2):

"hand" is not a supported style in browsers other than IE.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html